# Is it possible to log into all 6 terminal sessions at once?

Tags: command-line, terminal, login, session

If I press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to switch to the 1st terminal session, I have to give my username and password to log in. If I press Ctrl+Alt+F2, I have to repeat this process. Same for F3, F4, F5, and F6.

Is there a way that I can log into all of these terminal sessions at once? It's tedious to repeat this process if I want to use multiple terminal sessions.

Comment: Why not log in once and then use `screen` or `tmux` ?  Multiple sessions in one console, and you can disconnect and reconnect as needed

Comment: Why not use a graphical desktop? Their terminal emulators usually have more features than the console (more colors, styles, larger scrollback, search functionality and a whole lot more), plus you can use other kinds of apps (e.g. browsers) in the mean time. (If it's a server with no graphical system: it's usually more convenient to manage it remotely over ssh, rather than sitting in front of it.) I consider the console as a worst-case fallback if things go really wrong in the system. What's your use case for having to or wishing to use the text console?

Answer (score 3):

If your virtual consoles are being provided by `getty`, you can add this do your `systemd` configuration to automagically log in as a specific user on all `getty` consoles.  Note that this is hilariously insecure.

You'll have to make a new directory, `/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty2.service.d` (and another for each TTY beyond TTY2 for which you want this configuration change.  In that directory, create an `override.conf`.

In `/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty2.service.d/override.conf`:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=-/usr/bin/agetty --autologin username --noclear %I $TERM
```

**Please note** that anyone who wanders up to your console will be logged in as you and able to do what they please.